# Concatenate base url and path using urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, urllib, urlparse

I am trying to concatenate a base URL `url1` and a relative path `url2` using Python 3's [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html), but do not get the desired result. In addition I tried using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) (which is not meant to be used for this purpose) and simple [string concatenation using `.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
import os.path
import urllib.parse

url1 = "www.sampleurl.tld"
url2 = "/some/path/here"


print(urllib.parse.urljoin(url1, url2))
# --> "/some/path/here"

print(os.path.join(url1, url2))
# --> "/some/path/here"

print("{}{}".format(url1, url2))
# --> "www.sampleurl.tld/some/path/here" (desired output)
```

The simple string concatenation returns the desired absolute url. However, this approach seems to be very naive and not very elegant, since it assumes that `url2` starts with `/` which may not be the case. For sure, I could check this by calling [`url2.startswith('/')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and change the string concatenation to `"{}/{}".format(url1, url2)` to provide the desired flexibility, but I am still wondering how to do this in a proper way by means of [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[urljoin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) expects the first argument `baseurl` to include the schema.

So adding `https://` or `http://` for that matter to your `url1` string should do the job.

```
import urllib.parse

url1 = "https://www.sampleurl.tld"
url2 = "/some/path/here"


print(urllib.parse.urljoin(url1, url2))
# --> "https://www.sampleurl.tld/some/path/here"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.parse

url1 = 'www.sampleurl.tld'
url2 = '/some/path/here'

urlString = urllib.parse.ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc=url1, path=url2, params='', query='', fragment='')
urllib.parse.urlunparse(urlString)
```

You can try this. The URL is not created from a list, instead its from a class ParseResult.